# How can I access my ResourceDictionary?

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary

I have a ResourceDictionary called **CustomStyles.xaml** within in my project. It is located in a subdirectory called RD, therefore its location is **RD/CustomStyles.xaml**.

My question is the following: I have a **class-only** file called **CustomGroupBox.vb**, and in the New(), I would like to access resources from the ResourceDictionary.

How can I do this since I have no corresponding XAML for CustomGroupBox.vb?

P.S. I'd like to note that CustomStyles.xaml has a **BuildAction** of **Resource** and not **Content**, therefore it is compiled along with the project, it does NOT output to the build directory (\bin). Therefore the following wouldn't work...

```
Me.Resources.Source = New Uri("RD\CustomStyles.xaml")
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to use Application.Current.Resources to find your resources, assuming the resource dictionary is defined at the Application level.  Example:

```
YourControl.Style = CType(Application.Current.Resources("OneOfYourStyles"), Style)
```

Edit:  For a resource in an assembly and not the application, you can use Pack URI Syntax ([link](http://www.wiredprairie.us/journal/2007/06/pack_syntax_in_wpf.html)) to access the resource.  It would probably look something like this:

```
Dim u as Uri = New Uri("/" + Me.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name + ";RD/CustomStyles.xaml"
```

Comment: Sounds like someihing I did once, but i didn't need the 'Current' since I was in the file itself.

Comment: Actually, this didn't work for me. Since my files are in an assembly and not an application, I get the following error:

'Current' is not a member of 'MyApplication'

Comment: Ah, I see.  I think you can use Pack URI syntax to get a resource from an assembly.  Edited my answer with details.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can just pull the resource from the assembly.

This [blog](http://dotnet.org.za/craign/archive/2007/05/05/how-to-access-resources-embedded-in-an-assembly.aspx) post will show you how.